# Wallpaper history using cat and awk

Tags: bash, awk, cat, wallpaper, feh

I got the following script to randomize my background using feh:

```
#!/bin/sh
WPCURRENT="$(find ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/ -type f |shuf -n1)" 

feh --recursive --bg-fill "${WPCURRENT}"

echo -n ${WPCURRENT} > ~/.config/openbox/wallchange/wallpaper-history.txt
```

It saves the chosen wallpaper into the wallpaper-history.txt file. What i want to do is to use that file to store all wallpapers changes (a history) so that when i run a "previous" wallpaper command, it goes to the previous wallpaper.

Here's what i use to open the current wallpaper:

```
#!/bin/sh
IMG=$(cat ~/.config/openbox/wallchange/wallpaper-history.txt | awk -F "'|/" '{print $0}')
xviewer "${IMG}" &
exit
```

Comment: In the first script you're adding only one line to `~/.config/openbox/wallchange/wallpaper-history.txt` and whenever the script runs that history file will be overwritten. From your question it sounds like you want to append new line to that file every time, so that the file grows and not overwritten. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yes you are correct.